# Recharts PolarGrid polygons not showing

Tags: reactjs, polygon, recharts, radar-chart

I am trying to build a RadarChart with Rechart.

I need the chart to show 5 radius polygon lines and no angle line.
It works fine with circles, if I change property `gridType` of `<PolarGrid/>` from `'polygon'` to `'circle'`, I do have 5 concentric circles. But for some reason with `'polygon'` if I set `polarAngles={[]}` to remove angle lines, the polygons also disappear despite of
`polarRadius={[ 10, 20, 40, 60, 80 ]}`
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

```
        <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height='100%'>
          <RadarChart
            data={this.state.data.data}
            innerRadius='0%'
            outerRadius='70%'
            startAngle={-150}
            endAngle={210}
          >
            <PolarGrid 
              gridType='polygon'
              polarAngles={[]}
              polarRadius={[ 10, 20, 40, 60, 80 ]}
              stroke='#fff'
            />
            <PolarAngleAxis
              dataKey='kind'
              type='category'
              tickLine={false}
              tickFormatter={this.tickFormatter.bind(this)}
              stroke='#fff'
              axisLine={false}
            />
            <Radar dataKey="value" fill="#ff0101" fillOpacity={0.7} />
          </RadarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `polarAngles` array is needed to know at what points the corners of the polygon should be drawn, it should not be empty
If you need to remove radial lines, then for this you need to set the `radialLines` property to `false`

```
<PolarGrid
  gridType="polygon"
  polarRadius={[10, 20, 40, 60, 80]}
  stroke="#fff"
  radialLines={false}
/>
```